# MySQL get average from result, average must be between 8 and 12

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, average

So I am trying to create an MySQL query to get the average of the RANK id, and it must be somewhere between 8 and 12, otherwise the query will select 5 random player names until the RANKVALUE is averaged between 8 and 12.

```
select summonername 
from (select rankvalue from 
players group by summonername 
having count(rankvalue) = 5 
order by rand())
group by summonername
having avg(rankvalue) between 8 and 12
```

---

```
tid  PLAYER NAME   RANKVALUE
1   summonername2   5
1   Summoner 1      22
1   Summoner 2      10
1   Summoner 3      14
1   Summoner 4      10
1   Summoner 2      21
1   test            21
1   yop             13
1   summonername6   12
1   summonername7   16
1   summonername8   5
1   summonername9   13
1   summonername10  21
1   summonername11  1
1   summonername12  9
```

Comment: why the sql-server tag for a MySQL question?  The answers may be different depending on which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` and `Having` clause

```
SELECT `summonername`, AVG(rankvalue)
FROM `players` 
Where tid=1 
group by summonername
Having AVG(rankvalue) between 8 and 12
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is incredibly slow for large result sets. I don't use `HAVING` much but it seems like that might be very slow as well.

Comment: Doesn't get the results that is needed. It selects only the people that have their rank value between 8 and 12. I am trying to group 5 people, and get a rank value average from that.